# Extract pair key value on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7

I use this code for search a pair of value & key on multidimensional array

I need extract value of pair when lang is "en"

Its works for me but I thibk is not good code for PHP 7

```
$arr = [['lang' => null, 'title' => 'Main kaff'],
['lang' => 'en', 'title' => 'May way'],
['lang' => 'es', 'title' => 'Mi camino'],
['lang' => 'fr', 'title' => 'Mon chaimin']];

$key = "lang";

function multiSearch(array $array, array $pairs)
{
    $found = array();
    foreach ($array as $aKey => $aVal) {
        $coincidences = 0;
        foreach ($pairs as $pKey => $pVal) {
            if (array_key_exists($pKey, $aVal) && $aVal[$pKey] == $pVal) {
                $coincidences++;
            }
        }

        if ($coincidences == count($pairs)) {
            $found[$aKey] = $aVal;
        }
    }

    return $found;
} 

$x = multiSearch($arr,  array('lang' => 'en'));

var_dump($x);
```

The result is correct

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "May way"
  }
}
```

Comment: This question may be a better fit for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: Much easier if you structure array like: `$arr['lang']['en']['title'] = 'May way';`

Comment: @ZachGates Oops, I did not know the place. Is it possible to move the question?

Comment: It is possible, but I don't have a high enough reputation to do it. Hopefully a high-rep user or moderator can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Most simplified way:-***

```
<?php

$arr = [['lang' => null, 'title' => 'Main kaff'],
['lang' => 'en', 'title' => 'May way'],
['lang' => 'es', 'title' => 'Mi camino'],
['lang' => 'fr', 'title' => 'Mon chaimin']];

$lang= "en";

function multiSearch($arr,$lang)
{ 
   return $arr[array_search($lang,array_column($arr,'lang'))];  
}
$x = multiSearch($arr, $lang);
print_r($x);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/850435

***Elaborated way to understand what's going on:-***

```
<?php

$arr = [['lang' => null, 'title' => 'Main kaff'],
['lang' => 'en', 'title' => 'May way'],
['lang' => 'es', 'title' => 'Mi camino'],
['lang' => 'fr', 'title' => 'Mon chaimin']];

$lang= "en";// language you want to search

function multiSearch($arr,$lang)
{ 

   $array = array_column($arr,'lang'); // get lang-key all values as a single dimensional array from original multidimensional array
   $key = array_search($lang,$array); // get key based on search-language-match from this single dimensional array

    return $arr[$key]; // based on key return sub-array from original multi-dimensional array
} 

$x = multiSearch($arr, $lang);// call function with original array and language you want to search

print_r($x); // print output
```

Output:- https://eval.in/850427

Answer (score -1):

re-arrange your data and everything becomes so much easier:

```
$arrTitle = [
    null => 'Main kaff',
    'en' => 'May way',
    'es' => 'Mi camino',
    'fr' => 'Mon chaimin'
];

echo $arrTitle[null] . "\n";
echo $arrTitle['en'] . "\n";
```

**result:**
Main kaff
May way

Comment: Question it's not about data. Data it's a existent data, not modifibale. Question is about how to work with THIS data model.